# Can we have tickposition both outside and inside in highcharts?

Tags: highcharts, highcharts-ng

I am looking for a way to display tick markers on both side of axis. But highcharts api is allowing us to place it inside or outside and not both. Can someone share some pointers?

Answer (score 1):

One way achieve this look is to create two axes and link the first axis to the second one. Then one axis has tick-positions on the inside and the other on the outside. Like this:

```
xAxis: [{
  tickPosition: 'inside',
  labels: {
    enabled: false
  }
}, {
  linkedTo: 0
}],
```

Working [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/8vzz6g45/1/).

The labels are disabled on the inside axis to avoid double labels.